# comparing a dataframe with a .csv file using python

Tags: python, dataframe, bioinformatics, data-analysis

i have a .csv files which contains many data and i want to compare that with another .csv file and based on that i want to have an output file, for example my first file contains the data in following manner :-

[image]

and the second .csv file which named as second file, contains the list of the diseases which we need for example -:

[image]

so based on that our output file should be -:

[image]

i have written the python code for that, but i'm not getting the desired result, Please have a look-:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv("final.csv")
df1=pd.read_csv("diseases.csv")
df =df[df['extId'].isin(df.loc[df['Diseases'].isin(df1), 'extId'])]
df.to_csv("filtered.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can go about is to import your two csv's as `pandas` DataFrame, and then use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to check which extId's from `df1` are associated with `df2` Diseases:

```
import pandas as pd

print(
      df1[df1.extId.isin(\
                   df1.loc[df1.Diseases.isin(df2.Disesaes)]['extId'].values)\
    ]
          )

   extId Diseases
0    123      HIV
1    123    Fever
2    321   Cancer
```

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'extId':[123,123,321,456],
                    'Diseases':['HIV','Fever','Cancer','Diareah']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Disesaes':['HIV','Cancer']})
```